# getting "Cloud mapping experiment" and unexpected POST request on server in nginx log

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, server

I am getting unexpected requests in nginx access log on my server (aws-ec2). Sample shown below -

> 54.80.128.131 - - [05/Jul/2015:03:15:22 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Cloud mapping experiment. Contact research@pdrlabs.net"
>
> 204.15.135.116 - - [05/Jul/2015:03:29:23 +0000] "POST /cgi-bin/php?%2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%6F%72%63%65%5F%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%3D%30+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%5F%73%74%61%74%75%73%5F%65%6E%76%3D%22%79%65%73%22+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%69%78%5F%70%61%74%68%69%6E%66%6F%3D%31+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%6E
>   HTTP/1.1" 404 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0)
>   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"

What should I make of this? Should I be concerned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not.
What you see there is somebody hitting your server and requesting something that is not there (hence the 404s). The "CloudMapping Experiment" part is just the user agent that was passed in with the request.

Answer (score 1):

I can see similar questions concerning this user agent here, but no one seems to know what it does exactly : https://serverfault.com/questions/611335/cloud-mapping-experiment-contact-researchpdrlabs-net-in-the-access-logs

I saw this on 2 different networks, unrelated services.

Here is the last one i can see right now on a reverse proxy :

```
"GET /clientaccesspolicy.xml HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "-" "Cloud mapping experiment. Contact research@pdrlabs.net"
```

I suggest it may be some kind of vulnerability scanner trying to find vulnerable hosts.  In this case, it was looking for a file named /clientaccesspolicy.xml.  There seems to be ways to exploit those files if the server is back to a firewall, cause it could permit access to protected areas : https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerabilities/web/insecure-clientaccesspolicy-xml-file

**To answer your question now, the request :**

```
    POST /cgi-bin/php?  %2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%6F%72%63%65%5F%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%3D%30+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%5F%73%74%61%74%75%73%5F%65%6E%76%3D%30+%2D%6E HTTP/1.1
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26(KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

The request was an attempt to install an IRC bot written in Perl by exploiting a very old vulnerability in PHP.[1]

**This does not necessary mean your server was hacked.**  This simply means an attempt was made. It targeted Unix systems that ran a version of PHP susceptible to a 2-year-old vulnerability.  If you updated php at least once within the last 2 years, then you are more than probably ok :)

Someone tried to contact them at the email they provide in the user agent?  :)

[1]More infos on this page : https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/Web+Server+Attack+Investigation+Installing+a+Bot+and+Reverse+Shell+via+a+PHP+Vulnerability/18543/

Comment: I tried to, the email does not exist... Reported that IP on AbuseIPDB and now writing an abuse report.

Answer (score 0):

BLOCK THAT IP

26/06/2022
00:31:08
18.169.158.132
ec2-18-169-158-132.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

BLOCK THIS IP. SO IN YOUR HTACCESS

deny from 18.169.158.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).